# How can I do a background async task using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have a function something like this, using `Promises` and `NodeJS v6.10`:

```
function doSomeAsyncThings() {
    return this.doAsync().then((res) => {
        return this.logAsync().then(() => res)
    });
};
```

Now in context of the above example, `this.logAsync()` is not critical to my application, but more for recordkeeping purposes. For this reason, I was wondering if I could do this operation in the background, thus not waiting or its completion to return `res`?

Comment: it depends what u need. if its not critical don't wait/use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function doSomeAsyncThings() {
    return this.doAsync().then(value => {
        this.logAsync()
        // do things with your `value`
    });
};
```

Just don't wait for it.

Comment: `this.logAsync` does 2-3 async things itself, so if the function invoking it ends before `this.logAsync()` finishes, will the execution of `this.logAsync()` continue?

Comment: @AyushGupta Since `.logAsync` is asynchronous, it will continue to run in the background. We do not need to listen to its completion (with `.then`) because we don't care about its result. You can always test it out in your environment and see if it is working as expected.